# Adding a table to an existing PDF with itext5 in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, itext

I'm a newbie to java/kotlin programming, and this is my first project.
I have an existing pdf, created in another activity (activity1) with itext, passed to another activity (activity2) with an intent as "pdfPath".
I want to open that pdf and append a table at the end of that pdf with data acquired in activity2.
But every time i try it, my program eliminates everything on that pdf and just create another pdf with the table.
Here's the code:

```
            val pdfPath = intent.getStringExtra("pdfPath")
            val mDoc = Document()
            var writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(mDoc, FileOutputStream(pdfPath))
            mDoc.open()

            var table = PdfPTable(2)
            var imgTec = Image.getInstance(StoredPath)
            var cell = PdfPCell(imgTec)
            table.addCell(cell)

            cell = PdfPCell(Phrase("Signature"))
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell)
            mDoc.add(table)
            mDoc.close()
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: You mention iText 7 in your question title and in the tags but your code is using iText 5 or earlier. Thus, please decide and clarify.

Comment: Updated, i'm sorry

Comment: In iText 5 the `Document`/`PdfWriter` pairs are used to create new PDFs from scratch. For manipulating existing PDFs one usually uses a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` pair or (if the manipulation consists of adding new pages with content) a `Document`/`PdfWriter` pair to create the new content and then a `Document`/`PdfCopy` pair together with `PdfReader` instances to merge the base PDF and the PDF with the new contents.

Comment: I did this, but something's wrong in the writing part i think:
`val pdfPath = intent.getStringExtra("pdfPath")
val reader = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfPath)
val secondPdfName= //name
val secondPdfPath = //path
val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(secondPdfPath))
val column = ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1))
val rectPage = Rectangle(36F,10F,559F, 10F)
column.setSimpleColumn(rectPage)
var table = PdfPTable(1)
var cell = PdfPCell(Phrase("Test"))
table.addCell(cell)
column.addElement(table)
stamper.setFormFlattening(true)
stamper.close()
reader.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it:

```
val pdfPath = intent.getStringExtra("pdfPath")
val reader = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfPath)
val pdfName_write = "TEST_" + SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date()) + ".pdf"
val pdfPath_write = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + pdfName_write
val stamper = PdfStamper(reader, FileOutputStream(pdfPath_write))
val column = ColumnText(stamper.getUnderContent(1))

//Adjust the position of the rectangle
val rectPage = Rectangle(36F,36F,30F, 20F)

column.setSimpleColumn(rectPage)
var table = PdfPTable(2)

//Creating cell 1
var cell = PdfPCell(Phrase("TEST1"))
table.addCell(cell)
column.addElement(table)

//Creating cell 2
cell = PdfPCell(Phrase("TEST2"))
table.addCell(cell)
column.addElement(table)
column.go()

stamper.setFormFlattening(true)
stamper.close()
reader.close()
```

Comment: The first `column.go()` most likely is a no-operation as the table has no complete row at that time yet.